# Why can "NLPCloud" module be seen "Available Packages" on IntelliJ IDEA ultimate?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, module

I tried to use the [NLPcloud](https://nlpcloud.io) module on Node.js using IntelliJ IDEA.
However, the NLPcloud module did not show up in the "Available Packages" window of IntelliJ IDEA as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Nothing comes up on the list]

However, when I edit the package.json file, the module is suggested as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

And the module is present on the [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nlpcloud).

Does the "Available Packages" window in IntelliJ IDEA shown all the modules on npmjs.com?
And if not all modules are shown, then what modules are shown and what modules are not shown?
If you know, please let me know.

My development environment is here.
OS:macOS BigSur(11.4)
IDE:IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2021.1.1
Node.js:16.1
npm:7.15.0

Thanks!

Comment: Must the related to the API the dialog uses to retrieve packages from the registry, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28202#focus=Comments-27-2381581.0-0

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks!